# Force Index Not Working on Delete

Tags: sql, sybase, sap-ase

I am trying to use forced index on a delete statement in Sybase, but the query plan does not seems to pick the index, it is showing table scan.

What is the right way to force the index on delete?

Snippet of the query I am using:

```
SET FORCEPLAN ON

DELETE  #Table1
FROM  #Table2 tmp, #Table1 t (index idx1)
WHERE
    tmp.col1 = t.col1 and
    tmp.col2 = t.col2
```

The index idx1 is created on col1 and col2 on #Table1 which is the larger table.

Is there anything wrong in this query?
I am using Sybase ASE 12.5

Comment: Which table is being scanned?  How many total rows are you querying, and what percentage are in the temp table?  What's the complete query (or the smallest problem-reproducing version)?  Why are you trying to force use of an index?  Usually the optimizers are pretty good about figuring this stuff out...

Comment: Understand that one table will have go through a table scan in case of joins. if it's the smaller table then things are fine.

Do not use force index, let Sybase optimizer decide the plan.